# C++ std::map s as arguments

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

Is it possible for me to take an argument of any type of std::map?

```
void myFunction(const std::map<std::string,[INSERT_ANY_CLASS]>& tMap);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can make it a function template:

```
template<class T>
void myFunction(const std::map<std::string,T>& tMap);
```

Comment: And so long as class T supports the map construct - e.g. a proper copy constructor, etc.

Comment: @Blazes: solid point, with subtle implications.  While superficially it might seem that you wouldn't have a `map` of `T` to call the function with if `T` wasn't a type compatible with `map`'s requirements, it's typically the first function that instantiates one of the `map` template's methods that the class doesn't support that will trigger the compiler error....

Comment: That's all a bit irrelevant here, isn't it? The caller must have the map to start with. This function can safely assume that `T` is a valid type.